# API gateway - how do I get the resource policy attached to a particular deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway instance that has a working deployment. A newer deployment was pushed, that breaks the resource policy and causes it to fail with a 403 error. Fixing that issue can be solved with a rollback. However, finding the difference between the working resource policy and the broken new one has proven difficult.

How can I get the current, running, resource policy for a deployment on an API gateway stage?

Comment: Question title says older, question content says current - which one do you need sorry?

Comment: I rolled it back - it's currently set to use an older deployment. I've updated the question to avoid confusion.